# How import fabric-webpack to react-native?

Tags: swift, reactjs, react-native

I have existing iOS swift application. I integrate it to react-native. But when i added "import {Canvas,Circle, Image, Path} from 'react-fabricjs';" i have error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef0T9.jpg)

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "uploader",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Uploader",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "~15.3.0",
    "react-fabricjs": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native": "~0.34.0",
    "jsdom": "~9.9.1"
  }
}
```

my index.ios.js

```
'use strict';
// 1
import React from 'react';
import {Canvas,Circle, Image, Path } from 'react-fabricjs';


import ReactNative, {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
// 2
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 35,
    color: 'green',
  },
});

// 3
class AddRatingApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>See you later alligator !</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

// 4
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AddRatingApp', () => AddRatingApp);
```

How I can import any React library into react-native application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any libraries that uses html/css/DOM will not work with React Native. This one is a html5 library that will work with React, but not React Native.

Comment: Thank you for answer. And there is no way to connect React libraries?

Comment: React libraries work and you're importing it correctly, but React Native won't be able to understand libraries that use html/ccs/dom in them.

Comment: You should try to find a react-native library that does what you're trying to accomplish. Here is a good resource - https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native